# Ask Question 'Side Pannel' section, vertical overflow issue

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

I found an overflow issue pertaining to the 'How to' section, which typically appears to the right side of the 'Ask Question' site. When scrolling to the bottom of the site it overflows over the footer section. I believe this behavior should be fixed as it is visually displeasing (as a Front End developer myself, I can state this without prejudice).

Please see the attached image:

[image: Right sidebar issue]